# NodeJS Implement http response to tell browser to POST data to endpoint

Tags: node.js, request, postback

I'm trying to mimick a 3rd party server that is performing external verification and on success it will perform a "postback" (* *think this is a ASP pattern) to my app.

I'm using a nodejs server to mimick this 3rd party server (skipping the verification part).  So when it receives the request it basically just needs to respond with "something", that will tell the browser to POST some data to my app.

It's difficult to tell how this 3rd party server is telling the browser to perform the POST.  A normal redirect will not work as this performs a GET on the location.  I need it to do a POST.

Comment: Why do you need POST? If you need to send some data then you can use GET and use querystring for the data. `example.com/redir?data=blahblah

Comment: it's considered sensitive information

Comment: Try the 307 response, or the workaround mentioned here: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect

Comment: 307 doesn't work on chrome - really need a cross-browser solution anyway.  Going to try the workaround with responding with a interstitial HTML page, doesn't feel like that is what this 3rd party server is doing though, but it could work